# I hired a fire godlike, how do I get these pillars to work?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In the first cave area, there is a room full of pillars. Interacting with these pillars does not seem to work if you are not a fire godlike. I went and hired a fire godlike at the next inn and doubled back, but the dialog is still unavailable as "the requirement is not met".

How do I deal with these pillars?

[image: Screenshot of fire godlike standing next to pillar with the failed interaction message]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to carry a **Torch** in your inventory. (No requirement to equip it.)

The Fire Godlike option only works if the *player character* is a Fire Godlike; it won't work with a companion NPC.

All that said, there's no point in going back to light them. All it does is disable a pathway through the trap file grid in the adjoining room - and if you're doubling back, you've clearly either gotten through it with the Mechanics skill or just gone around it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a torch, you can light the pillars with that. I'm not sure if you have to equip the torch or just carry it in your inventory, though.

It is also not strictly necessary to light the pillars, there is another way to get out of the cave.